# Compile and upgrade to PHP 5 on linux with old php settings how to?

Tags: linux, php

I am running CentOS i need to compile and install PHP 5 there but i never done this before is this still possible or i need to find someone to do it for me?

There is already installation of PHP 4 and site running on it, my major problem is how can i import settings from php 5.1.6 into php 5.3.6 prior to compilation or after please advice!

Answer (score 1):

Try out some of the pre-packaged php 5.3 RPMs:

http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/5/remi/x86_64/repoview/

If you need to recompile with some specific options, his SRPMs are a good starting point.

Comment: I need "ZIP" extension so far i read for CentOS you can use "yum install php" or "yum update php" but my questiona bout old options is still open

Comment: You need to download a SRPM, such as this: http://rpms.famillecollet.com/SRPMS/php-5.3.6-3.remi.src.rpm  You will then edit the .spec file and add your needed compile options.